# Unable to plot different graph in Plotly.py

Tags: python-3.x, plotly, plotly-python

Unable to plot different graph together. It works if plotting separately or in groups of 2 or 3 (so the code is correct) but when putting all in the same fig the browser times out.

sometimes if I omit "xaxis_rangeslider_visible=False" works. Feels like running out of memory but I don't think the plot is that heavy.

Any suggestion to improve my code?  Python 3.7.7

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

df2 =df.tail(85)
fig = go.Figure()


fig.add_trace(go.Ohlc(x=df2.index, open=df2['Open'], high=df2['High'], low=df2['Low'], close=df2['Close']))
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df2.index, y=df2['ema13'],opacity=0.7, line=dict(color='blue', width=2)))
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df2.index, y=df2['ema20'],opacity=0.7, line=dict(color='red', width=2) ))
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df2.index, y=df2['ema30'],opacity=0.7, line=dict(color='green', width=2)))
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df2.index, y=df2['P'],mode='markers', marker=dict(symbol=mark)))
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=df2.index, y=df2['A'], marker_color=df2['A_color']))

fig.update_layout(xaxis_rangeslider_visible=False)
fig.show()
```

I tried replacing the data frame for lists to make it lighter but without success.

I tried to replicate the plot from "Backtesting.py" (optimizer) but I was lost reading the code. I manage to run some examples with 10 years of data and they used an interactive cursor. Much more heavy than my plot (discarding lack of hardware or dependency's issues)

Initially wanted to plot 1000 rows but had to reduce to 85 to be able to plot up to 5 graph together.

Comment: If you review and comment on the Colab, the link will be disabled.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
If the code is correct, any suggestion on my issue (python version, dependencies)?

I have been working on this for a while but stuck on the fix. Plots work separately, so code and dataset is correct.

Comment: The only difference with yours is my native python launches a browser to plot the graphs. There is no errors, the browser just times out.

Comment: If it is a graph browser, it is not in the code in your question, but changing the renderer to browser will substitute the output for the browser. since it is not valid in the Colab environment, I added the following code in my local environment and ran the code you shared. `import plotly.io as pio;pio.renderers.default = "browser"` The graph was displayed correctly in the browser.

Comment: pio.renderers.default = "browser" didn't fix the issue but following your line of work. I changed the default browser to chrome as pio.renderers.default = "chrome" or "firefox" didn't work.  (ValueError: Can't locate a browser with key in ('chromium', 'chromium-browser'))

I tried to update webbrowser._browser.keys but didn't manage to fix the issue
Appreciate your help and speed